# Modbus rtu unable to read all data

Tags: c#, serial-port, console-application, modbus

I am working on `modbus` protocol using `RS485`. My frame is `01 03 00 00 00 61 84 22`. While passing this frame I am able to see a response but if I set my frame `01 03 00 00 00 62 C4 23` I am getting no response.

```
var items = new byte[]{ Convert.ToByte(iterations.hex), 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x61 };
var crc = BitConverter.GetBytes(ModRTU_CRC(items, items.Length));
port.BaseStream.Write(dataItems, 0, dataItems.Length);

            receivedBytes = port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
            var receiveData = BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
```

Here my `recieveBytes` is `0`. I have tried everything but still, I am unable to get all the required data. My total frame is `01 03 00 00 00 78 45 E8` but the count greater than `61` gives me no response.

**Update 1**

Below is my request and response.

**request frame :** `01 03 00 00 00 61 84 22`

**response frame**

```
01 slave id
03 function code
B4 further bytes
00 20 97 01 msn
00 01 slave 
25 80 baud rate
3F 82 8F 5C Hardware ver
3F 80 00 00 Soft ver
00 00 // unknown-not required
44 7A 00 00 // unknown-not required
00 05 // unknown-not required
01 01 // unknown-not required
00 05 // unknown-not required
43 61 E6 66 L1 volt
00 00 00 00 L2 volt
00 00 00 00 L3 volt
42 47 28 F6 Grid freq
40 24 7A E1 L1 curry
00 00 00 00 L2 curry
00 00 00 00 L3 curry
3F 14 7A E1 Total act pow
3F 14 7A E1 T1
00 00 00 00 T2
00 00 00 00 T3
3B A3 D7 0A Total react pow
3B A3 D7 0A T1
00 00 00 00 T2
00 00 00 00 T3
3F 14 7A E1 Total apprt pow
3F 14 7A E1 T1
00 00 00 00 T2
00 00 00 00 T3
3F 80 00 00 Total pow fac
3F 80 00 00 T1
00 00 00 00 T2
00 00 00 00 T3
02 20 15 04 // unknown-not required
09 07 20 00 // unknown-not required
00 00 // unknown-not required
75 A3 // unknown-not required
41 E7 EB 85 Total act eng
41 E7 EB 85 T1
00 00 00 00 T2
00 00 00 00 T3
41 E7 EB 85 Fwd act enrg
41 E7 EB 85 T1
00 00 00 00 T2
00 00 00 00 T3
00 00 00 00 Rev act enrg
00 00 00 00 T1
00 00 00 00 T2
00 00 00 00 T3
3E 8F 5C 29 Total react eng
3E 8F 5C 29 T1
00 00 00 00 T2 
00 00 00 00 T3
C3 FE
```

**Remaining values:** Fwd reactive energies and reverse reactive energies which are beyond count `61`

Comment: What device are you sending the data to?  Or are you trying to simulate the interface?   What you are doing is not rtu according to attached document : https://www.rtautomation.com/technologies/modbus-rtu/

Comment: Device is the meter.

Comment: The links says it is 1 start bit 8 data bits a Even Parity 1 stop.  So do you setup UART properly and Baud rate properly?  Is CRC correct (see https://ctlsys.com/support/how_to_compute_the_modbus_rtu_message_crc/)?  Where is your address and function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Modbus_RTU_frame_format_(primarily_used_on_asynchronous_serial_data_lines_like_RS-485/EIA-485)

Comment: The CRC is correct for testing i am using comixx

Comment: Is algorithm same the seeds the CRC the same with 0xA001

Comment: @jdweng didn't get you

Comment: What CRC is comixx using?  Not all CRC algorithms are the same.  There are a few basic CRC algorithms but they need to be seeded correctly.  So you need to be using the correct algorithm and the correct seed.

Comment: The above mentioned CRC is what comix using. Also I want to add that if I try to read some specific value after the count `62` then it returns me the value. e.g. reading from `0128` to `012E` returns me all the values of `Reverse Reactive Energies`. But in my case I am getting nothing after the count `61`

Comment: I know nothing about comixx and can't find anything on the net.  Modbus rtu requires a address and function and all I see is your data.  It looks like you have two questions 1) Why you are getting no response 2) When you get a response you want to read after count 61.  I've been trying to solve issue 1.  Do not have enough info to solve 2.  I need to see a response and know if you are getting ascii or binary.

Comment: @jdweng Please see my update1

Comment: Most likely reason is a bug in the CRC algorithm.  Compare the CRC value in the link I provided with your CRC.  First make sure a number less than 61 works and then try with number that doesn't work.  I would suspect if the there was a limit on count you would get an error message back.  Here you are getting nothing back which is usually caused by bed CRC.

Comment: @jdweng count `61` and less than it is working.

Comment: @jdweng moreover I have setup UART and Baud Rate properly

Comment: @jdweng also I am using the same crc algo

Comment: See Sunshine which I used a lot in the past.  Set CRC to 16 and then in pulldown select Modbus : http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html  The seed in Sunshine is 0x8005 while sample code is 0xA001.  Notice the seeds are backwards.  Try sending a different CRC with your working example and see if it breaks.

Comment: CRC is correct.  Looks like you  exceeded max frame size of 255 bytes.  Your good message has 199 bytes and there is an additional 28 start bytes and 28 end bytes adding to 255,  See Wiki for 28 Start and 28 End : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus

Comment: @jdweng so there is no solution to send the frame once and receive all the data?

Comment: There is a max size and you cannot exceed the size.